# How modern electronic parking brake works? Do they consume power when parked and car is off?

Tags: battery, car, electronics, parking, parking-brake

This might be a stupid question, but lately I've been asking myself this question and couldn't find an answer on google.

How modern electronic parking brakes work? Do they consume power when parked and car is off?

Or are the calipers, by default, extended (applying brakes) and the car must open them in order for it to drive.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these systems do not consume energy when activated.  While there are several different designs, all are based on a motorized actuator that engages the brake.  So it only is "on" for the short time it takes to push the brake shoes or pads into position.  Then it's on again for the time it takes to move them away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but are they hydraulic brakes or it's another design?

Comment: Some are hydraulic and many use the ABS pump to pressurize the system and engage the brakes.  Others have an electric actuator that applies pressure to the braking surface.  There is no one-size-fits-all here.  There are many vendors and auto makers and each make their own decisions on design.